# Is it still necessary to keep copy, paste and cut under Edit?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

`Right click -> Copy / Paste / Cut`  and `Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V` has been around for awhile now. Most applications has this, yet they still add Copy / Paste / Cut under the Edit menu. Even in software used mostly by power users.

Why is it still necessary to add them under an Edit menu? Will users have difficulty finding them if it's only in the right click menu?

Comment: One thing to consider is that many accessibility software (such as software for those without the use of their hands) rely on being able to navigate through the menus rather than triggering shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't underestimate the power of habit among users.**

These functionalities have been accessible under the Edit menu in a wide variety of programs for the last 20+ years.  While it may seem easier or more efficient to use the CRTL commands or right click, many users who started out accessing these functionalities under the Edit menu have never stopped doing so.  I work with many IT "power users" who have been in the field for decades and I've seen them access these functionalities under the Edit menu because that's where they accessed them originally and have never stopped.

**What do you have to lose from putting these functionalities under the Edit menu?**

There would be consequences for not including these functionalities under the Edit menu for the small number of users who are used to accessing it there.  While they may eventually figure out the options are available via right click, having to change their ingrained behaviors will interrupt their work flow.  With that being said, what do you stand to lose by including them?  It's not likely that you would cause any harm or confusion by including these menu options there, especially since they've been a common presence for so long.

Comment: I’ve worked some freelance IT occassiaonlly in the past, and I’d add that there are a ton of users who generally only understand how to use any function of a computer by step by step lists. If they encounter something that breaks their list, like copy, cut, and paste not being in the edit menu, they’ll be totally unable to continue onwards and will likely never look up how to get around the problem. 

Here’s a great study on computer literacy around the world. [NN Group Study Results](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/computer-skill-levels/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to have an Edit menu in the first place (for converting EOL or whatever), is there a need to hide the fact that it's actually possible copy/paste/cut (a.k.a. edit) in your application?

There might be a feature that prevents using of a shortcut (using `Ctrl+C` to copy a whole "item" instead of just some selected text) or a bug that prevents context menu commands, so in rare cases the normal menu commands might be useful.

But I wouldn't call it "necessary" if you find more benefits by not showing these commands in main menu.